# MySQL (MariaDB) crashing

Tags: mysql, memory, innodb, mariadb, outofmemoryerror

Good morning - I have reviewed a previous post regarding changing the performance schema to "Off in the configuration settings. It looks as though our configuration is already set to this. So not sure what might be causing the crashing issues.

```
[root@#### etc]# vim my.cnf

[mysqld]

general_log             = 1

general_log_file=/var/log/mariadb/query.log



datadir=/var/lib/mysql

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock



symbolic-links=0

innodb_file_per_table = 1

#thread_stack = 131072

# mgk change 11/23/15

thread_stack = 256k

net_buffer_length = 2K

read_rnd_buffer_size = 256K

read_buffer_size = 256K

sort_buffer_size = 64K

table_open_cache = 4

max_allowed_packet = 1M

key_buffer_size = 16K

performance_schema = off
```

Here is a log summary

```
InnoDB: mmap(137756672 bytes) failed; errno 12

160329 11:44:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

160329 11:44:50 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

160329 11:44:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

160329 11:44:50 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

160329 11:44:50 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)

160329 11:44:50 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)

160329 11:44:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

160329 11:44:50 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

160329 11:44:50 [ERROR] Aborting

160329 11:44:50 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160329 11:44:50 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended

160329 12:46:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql

160329 12:46:48 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44-MariaDB-log) starting as process 7488 ...

160329 12:46:48 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled

160329 12:46:48 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins

160329 12:46:48 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7

160329 12:46:48 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

160329 12:46:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M

160329 12:46:48 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

160329 12:46:48 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.

InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 2502249177

160329 12:46:48  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!

InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
```

Comment: Can you show memory usage? Can you also show more of the log? Right now it looks like you should increase your memory on the machine.

Comment: Frank - here you go, I think this is what you are asking for:
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3950        1573        1125          76        1251        2232
Swap:           511         254         257

Answer (score 1):

> 160329 11:44:50 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)

Per @michael-sqlbot looks like  [Ubuntu 12.04 Server - MySQL keeps crashing - Possible InnoDB problems - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/560541/ubuntu-12-04-server-mysql-keeps-crashing-possible-innodb-problems/560554#560554) covers your issue.

Comment: Alexus - this is a 4gb machine. I am looking to isolate when the crash happened and as to why. Right now there are no issues that I can see. I just restarted mysql. 

However with this being the second time that it happened, I am looking into it further.

Comment: **Stop.** `160329 11:44:50 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB` does **not** mean InnoDB is misconfigured.  That message is a side effect of InnoDB failing to initialize the buffer pool -- due to insufficient memory -- which is the *only* problem there's any evidence for, here:  `160329 11:44:50 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool` is the only meaningful error message.  $20 says Apache is also running on the same machine.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/a/560554/153161